# update dataframe value by timestamp scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, bigdata, spark-streaming

I have this dataframe

```
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|customerid|     |  event                      | A                  | B            |    C           |
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|     1222222    | 2019-02-07 06:50:40.0       |aaaaaa              | 25           | 5025           |
|     1222222    | 2019-02-07 06:50:42.0       |aaaaaa              | 35           | 5000           |
|     1222222    | 2019-02-07 06:51:56.0       |aaaaaa              | 100          | 4965           |
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I want to update the value of column C by event (tiemstamp) and keep only the row with the latest value update in new dataframe like this

```
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|customerid|     |  event                      | A                  | B            |    C           |
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|     1222222    | 2019-02-07 06:51:56.0       |aaaaaa              | 100          | 4965           |
+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
```

the data are coming in streaming mode with spark streaming

Comment: What have you done so far? It looks like you need to group the rows by some common key (groupBy), then take a record from each group with the max timestamp. Then map remain records from each group.

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov yes exactly i have many event with key i want to to take the last event by timestamp and the last value of C automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating row number partitioned by customerid and order by event desc and take the rows where rownum is 1. I hope this helps.

```
df.withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("customerid").orderBy(col("event").desc)))
    .filter(col("rownum") === 1)
    .drop("rownum")
```